# What do the brackets after func mean in Go?

Tags: go

As a Go beginner, I [stumbled across code](https://github.com/getlantern/lantern/blob/2.0.2/src/github.com/blang/semver/json.go#L8) where there are brackets directly after `func`

```
func (v Version) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
  return json.Marshal(v.String())
}
```

So what does `(v Version)` mean?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not a function but a method. In this case, it adds the MarshalJSON method to the Version struct type.

The `v` is the name for the received value (and would be analogous to *this* in a Java method or *self* in Python), the Version specifies the type we're adding the method to.

See [go by example](https://gobyexample.com/methods) for, well, an example, and the [specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations) for more details.

Comment: An important thing to note is that you can attach a function receiver to any type in go, it need not be a struct.

Comment: Great! Thank you! I didn't yet make it to [methods in the go tour](http://tour.golang.org/methods/1) :-/

Comment: @robbmj: Weirdest use of that I have seen yet is attaching a function to a function pointer.

Comment: @ZanLynx A good example of that would be attaching a `ServeHTTP` method on a custom function type so that it implements `http.Handler`. Not that weird at all!

Comment: @elithrar: It starts to look like code obfuscation when you've got to dig through `f.ServeHTTP()`, `f()`, `f().PerformAction()`, etc.

Comment: That's a variable naming problem: if you're using short names beyond a short scope (i.e. a 10 line function) then it certainly becomes confusing! If that was (e.g.) `authHandler.ServeHTTP(w, r)` it'd be much clearer. I don't think that's an argument for *not* having methods on any types, though.